# db 1054 unknow column when login django admin site using custom model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have implement my custom User model,that worked fine,I created a superuser and use that account to sign in django default admin site,and failed,the error page
displayed

```
OperationalError at /admin/login/
(1054, "Unknown column 'user.name' in 'field list'")
```

Below are my whole codes:

**myadmin/modes.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, chinesename,
                        first_name,status, last_name,password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
           raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            chinesename=chinesename,
            status=status,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,chinesename,
                        first_name, status, last_name, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            chinesename=chinesename,
            password=password,
            status=status,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    STATUS = (
        (0,'on'),
        (1,'off')
    )
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key')
    #user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50,help_text='administrator email')
    chinesename = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50,help_text='administrator name')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #password = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text='administrator password')
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS,help_text='administrator status')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('chinesename','status','first_name','last_name',)
    #objects = UserManager()
    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.status
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APP=
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_swagger',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'jwtauth',
 'navigation',
 'myadmin',
 'article')
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
```

**mysql user table:**

mysql> desc user;

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| password    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| chinesename | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name  | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name   | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createtime  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modifytime  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: i have fixed , because of the server not restarting